# Get specific values of JSON object java

Tags: java, json

Currently I'm using following to get specific data from a JSON object. Where I keep the key as a primary key in a DB.

```
"10005": {
        "test": {
            "status": "C",
            "value": "2021/01/05",
            "currency": "USD",
            "amount": 35000.0
        },
  

      String key = keys.next();
                        if (jsonObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                            JSONObject object = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get(key);
                            Iterator<String> keysInside = object.keys();
                            while (keysInside.hasNext()) {
                                String keyIn = keysInside.next();
                                if (object.get(keyIn) instanceof JSONObject) {
                                    JSONObject objectInside = (JSONObject) object.get(keyIn);
                                    switch (keyIn) {
                                        case "test_1":
```

How do I iterate through if the JSON object has another loop like this

```
{
    "10005": {
        "001": {
            "test": {
                "staus": "C",
                "value": "2021/01/05",
                "currency": "USD",
                "amount": 35000.0
            },
```

Comment: This seems incredibly convoluted. What value(s) are you actually interested in finding in the JSON? What do you want to do with those values?

Comment: I think here could be a recursive approach make sense

Comment: This is actually for a personal project. These will be saved into a DB to retrieve & display later. Using my code I can retrieve the necessary values from the JSON object. But I'm not sure how to retrieve values when  "001":  comes